# Cannot fetch api - "Unhandled promise rejection"

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, asynchronous, react-hooks

I've got a question, can someone told me, am I right or not but react native api fetch working randomly?
Can someone also tell me maybe what I need to read to understand how it works because I want to make "pokedex" but I cant fetch api, I've got somethink like this

```
    const getDataFromApi = async () => {
    let cancel;
    const res = await axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon", {
      cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken((c) => (cancel = c)),
    });
    const data = await res.data.results.map((m) => m);

    setPokemon(data);

    return () => cancel();
  };
    useEffect(() => {
        getDataFromApi();
      }, [currentPageUrl]);
```

And then I'm passing parameters

```
<ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.containerOfTiles}>
      {pokemon.map((item) => (
        <Pokecard style={styles.tileContainer}>{item}</Pokecard>
      ))}
      {/* <Pokelist pokemon={pokemon} /> */}
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
```

And in Pokecard I'm fetching pokemon per Card, and It looks like that

```
    const getPokemonData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(url);

    const pokemonObject = await JSON.stringify(res.data);
    setPokemonData(pokemonObject);
    console.log(pokemonData.height);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getPokemonData();
  }, []);
```

In console, shows undefined (only once showed normal height)

My problems:
If I want to use that parameters from pokemonData, for example type of pokemon It doesn't work if I'll jump in to this screen first time but when I'm in and saving any changes then this works, in other way is problem of undefined parameter.

Second problem, every first time in this screen then in shows "Unhandled promise rejection" but when I'll delete console.log then It is not showing any warning

Sorry, if somethink I wrote is not clear, explain and I'll try my best to correct my question

(I think I'm doing somethink wrong) Thank you in advance

//EDIT
Poke card function komponent

```
export default function Pokecard(props) {
  const url = props.children.url;
  const pokemonIndex = url.split("/")[url.split("/").length - 2];
  const imageUrl = `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/home/${pokemonIndex}.png`;

 
  const colorsTiles = [
    {
      rock: "rgb(148, 81, 81)",
      ghost: "rgb(247, 247, 247)",
      electric: "rgb(255, 255, 161)",
      bug: "#F6D6A7",
      poison: "#e0a7f6",
      normal: "#F4F4F4",
      fairy: "rgba(255, 192, 203, 0.863)",
      fire: "#FBE3DF",
      grass: "#E2F9E1",
      water: "#E0F1FD",
    },
  ];
  const [pokemonData, setPokemonData] = useState([]);

  const getPokemonData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(url).then(() => {});

    const pokemonObject = await JSON.stringify(res.data);
    setPokemonData(pokemonObject);
    console.log(pokemonData.height);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getPokemonData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <View
      key={props.children.name}
      style={[styles.tileContainer, { backgroundColor: "white" }]}
    >
      <Text style={styles.pokemonName}>{props.children.name}</Text>
      <View style={styles.imageBG}>
        <Image
          style={styles.pokemonImage}
          source={{
            uri: imageUrl,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

AND Second Component (Main of this pokedex)

```
export default function Pokedex({ navigation }) {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([]);
  const [currentPageUrl, setCurrentPageUrl] = useState(
    "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon"
  );
  const [nextPageUrl, setNextPageUrl] = useState();
  const [prevPageUrl, setPrevPageUrl] = useState();

  const getDataFromApi = async () => {
    let cancel;
    const res = await axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon", {
      cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken((c) => (cancel = c)),
    });
    const data = await res.data.results.map((m) => m);

    setPokemon(data);

    return () => cancel();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getDataFromApi();
  }, [currentPageUrl]);
  return (
    <View
      style={[globalStyles.container, { backgroundColor: "rgb(43,41,44)" }]}
    >
      <BackButton navigation={navigation} />

      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.containerOfTiles}>
          {pokemon &&
            pokemon.map((item) => (
              <Pokecard style={styles.tileContainer}>{item}</Pokecard>
            ))}
          {/* <Pokelist pokemon={pokemon} /> */}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

//EDIT 2
WHEN I Changed to somethink like this

```
const getPokemonData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(url);

    const pokemonObject = await res.data;
    console.log(pokemonObject.types[0].type.name);
    setPokemonData(pokemonObject);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getPokemonData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <View
      key={props.children.name}
      style={[
        styles.tileContainer,
        { backgroundColor: colorsTiles[0][pokemonData.types[0].type.name] },
      ]}
    >
      <Text style={styles.pokemonName}>{props.children.name}</Text>
      <View style={styles.imageBG}>
        <Image
          style={styles.pokemonImage}
          source={{
            uri: imageUrl,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

then I've got error "Undefined is not an object (evaluating pokemonData.Types[0])"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing your code and doing some edits the result was

Pokecard.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Image, Text, View } from "react-native";

const colorsTiles = {
    rock: "rgb(148, 81, 81)",
    ghost: "rgb(247, 247, 247)",
    electric: "rgb(255, 255, 161)",
    bug: "#F6D6A7",
    poison: "#e0a7f6",
    normal: "#F4F4F4",
    fairy: "rgba(255, 192, 203, 0.863)",
    fire: "#FBE3DF",
    grass: "#E2F9E1",
    water: "#E0F1FD",
};

const typeToColor = (pokemonType) => {
    return colorsTiles[pokemonType] ?? "white";
};

export default function Pokecard(props) {
    const url = props.pokemon.url;
    const pokemonIndex = url.split("/")[url.split("/").length - 2];
    const imageUrl = `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/home/${pokemonIndex}.png`;

    const [pokemonData, setPokemonData] = useState(undefined);
    const [pokemonType, setPokemonType] = useState(undefined);

    const getPokemonData = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(url);
            setPokemonData(res.data);
            setPokemonType(res.data.types[0]?.type?.name);
        } catch (err) {}
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        getPokemonData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <View key={props.pokemon.name}>
            <Text>{props.pokemon.name}</Text>
            <View>
                {pokemonData && (
                    <Image
                        style={[
                            { height: 100 },
                            {
                                backgroundColor: typeToColor(pokemonType),
                            },
                        ]}
                        source={{
                            uri: imageUrl,
                        }}
                    />
                )}
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

and pokdex file

```
const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([]);
    const [currentPageUrl, setCurrentPageUrl] = useState(
        "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon"
    );
    const [nextPageUrl, setNextPageUrl] = useState();
    const [prevPageUrl, setPrevPageUrl] = useState();

    const getDataFromApi = async () => {
        let cancel;
        const res = await axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon", {
            cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken((c) => (cancel = c)),
        });
        const data = await res.data.results;

        setPokemon(data);

        return () => cancel();
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getDataFromApi();
    }, [currentPageUrl]);

    return (
        <View
            style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}
        >
            <View>
                {pokemon.map((item) => (
                    <Pokecard pokemon={item} />
                ))}
                {/* <Pokelist pokemon={pokemon} /> */}
            </View>
        </View>
    );
```

didn't include styles and some other edits might be required like wrapping your axios calls with try catch to handle failures, but this should put you on the right track
[image]

Comment: Hello, it still showing warning about unhandled promise, I'll add Two components (I'm using them only for this pokedex)

Comment: Ok, after your edit answer: What if I want to put data, for example instead of background: "white" i want to put there type of pokemon and this shows me every time warning

Comment: I just edited post, and added what error shows (EDIT 2) If you know how to resolve that, or any tip I'll be grateful :)

Comment: sure let me test it on my end first

Comment: just edited my answer to give you a complete solution including the background color thingy, please mark and vote for the answer if it helped

Comment: It's better, now doesn't show any error so is nice, left one problem that tile isn't change own background color, it's left white but I'll try to resolve that. Thank you so much for help :)

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot the colors do change, just make sure instead of setting backgroundColor:"white" do backgroundColor:typeToColor(pokemonType) like in my example

Comment: Ok I found also why color doesn't change because in my case colors was in array :), I've changed on the way like you wrote. Working fine, no erros, Thank you very much !. I marked your answer :)